# display the images and audio

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app.I have a problem while developing  the app.
The problem is:

I have a UIImageView and audio.I have 20 images in an array .so i need to display the 20 images in this UIImageView within time interval.Along with the image i need to set the audio.I need to view in same time, ie  20 images and audio should come at same time.

my code as below.

```
  alphabetsStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.png",@"b.png",@"c.png",@"d.png",@"e.png",@"f.png",@"g.png",@"h.png",@"i.png",@"j.png",@"k.png",@"l.png",@"m.png",@"n.png",@"o.png",@"p.png",@"q.png",@"r.png",@"s.png",@"t.png",@"u.png",@"v.png",@"w.png",@"x.png",@"y.png",@"z.png", nil];


    commonFunctionObject = [[SpeechCommonFunctions alloc]init];
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    counter = 0;
    isMicPresent = YES;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatActionFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)repeatActionFire
{
    if(counter >= alphabetsStoreArray.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_alphabetsShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"congratulation.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(navNew) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

    }

    else
    {
        [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:alphabetsStoreArray :counter :_alphabetsShowImageView :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
}
-(void)navNew

{
    v11=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"maincontroller"];
    [self presentViewController:v11 animated:NO completion:nil];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }    */



-(IBAction)homebut:(id)sender{
    UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                  message:@"Message"
                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* Home = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"RETURN TO HOME"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {

                                    v11=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"maincontroller"];
                                    [self presentViewController:v11 animated:NO completion:nil];


                                }];
    UIAlertAction* Cancel = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                                               }];
    [alert addAction:Cancel];
    [alert addAction:Home];



    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)playButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [commonFunctionObject recordPlayAction];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    counter+=1;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}

- (IBAction)retryButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}
```

how to do?

Comment: get your audio seek time and divide it by image array count then set animation duration to UIImageview..see harish saran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585263/uiimage-animating-an-array-of-images

Comment: how to do here .can u please give the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, May be you need more than this, but here is a start to get you in the right direction.

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender { 
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
//all alloc does is allocate memory. The -init method is crucial to 
actually initialize the object into a working state.

 for (int imagenumber = 1; imagenumber <= 45; imagenumber++) {
 NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", imagenumber];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:myString]];
}
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 460);
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"%@/giggity stick around.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
resourcePath]]];
soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
error:nil];
soundPlayer.volume = 1;
[soundPlayer play];    

imageview.animationImages = images;

imageview.animationDuration = 3.2;

imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;

[imageview startAnimating];

[self.view addSubview:imageview];

}
```

Use the AVFoundation to play the audio.

Comment: have u checked this answer? @jesteena